# How to get Value of Button which id is bind dynamically in lightning salesforce

Tags: community, salesforce1-app, salesforce-id

> I try to get button value by document.getElementById(btnid).value but its return id

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb10 addtarget seemore" 
  onclick="{!c.c_UpdateUserTargetList}" value="Remove from Target List" 
  id="{!v.UTList.Id}" />`
```

--

```
c_UpdateUserTargetList: function(component,event,helper)
{
   var btnid=event.target.id; 
   var btnvalue=document.getElementById(btnid).value;
}
```

Comment: your code should return `button` value properly not sure why its not working can add more code to debug the issue?. Also you can directly access the `button` value from the event.target itself like this : `event.target.value`

Comment: I have added the comment as the answer, can  you mark it as accepted ? so that we can close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code should return button value properly, but not sure why its not working.

Instead of getting the `id` and again using it, to find the element.you can get `value` using the `event.target` reference too, all you have to do is get the value like this : `event.target.value`